# Getting query params in angular 6 with useHash true for IE 9

Tags: angular6

I am working on angular 6.

My URL was like

```
http://localhost:4200/login?param1=123&param2=abc
```

This was in other browsers like chrome, firefox and IE 10 and 11.

But with IE 9 we need to route along with hash. So it was like

```
http://localhost:4200/login#/login?param1=123&param2=abc
```

I am not able to get the query params from here.

Answer (score 2):

There is no so much setup/code information in your answer but i guess you have to activate the hashes in your angular project. Please see the code below and let me know when it was helpful/useful.

This pattern is called [hashlocationstrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy)(official documentation)

Example code:

`@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    ...
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }`

Comment: This what I tried. While getting query params using ActivatedRoute. It returns undefined.

The url is http://localhost:4200/login#/login?param1=123

I need the param1 value

Comment: Did you see the difference (except #) between `http://localhost:4200/login?param1=123&param2=abc` and `http://localhost:4200/login#/login?param1=123&param2=abc` (ass you described in your issue)! 
There are 2 different urls.

Maybe you have prescribed yourself and it should be written `http://localhost:4200/#login?param1=123&param2=abc`

Comment: @GaneshKumar please inform us if you solved your issue, thanks.

Comment: http://localhost:4200/login-ui/login#/login?lang=en-US&view_type=login&code=9bd7c8bd-8b03-4058-8853-76130bf62ac2

this is my url when I use RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) in IE 9

Here, login-ui is the context path, login is the component name. I want to get the code value in query parameter

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you want!  Maybe someone other can help you or you describe your issue in way where all of us understanding them.